# If you can't draw, is that an indication of low spatial IQ?

Tags: iq, spatial-cognition

People who can draw obviously can visualize space and objects in their mind. Therefore, people who can't draw obviously cannot. So does that mean that people who can't draw must have low spatial IQ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'can't draw'? Do you mean making an artistic expression with esthetic quality, or down to drawing simple shapes, like a rectangle?

Comment: I meant for example being able to draw a human hand or something. I do not mean drawing in the artistic sense. I simply mean the ability to draw a realistic 2D representation on paper of any object from memory.

Comment: I don't want to nitpick, but what is a 'realistic' hand? A circle with 5 ovals as it faithfully depicts its overall shape? Or does it have to include 3 joints on the fingers, two on the thumb, pores, nails etc etc. I think it all depends on how you define 'realistic'. And drawing a hand from memory is difficult since you need it to draw the hand in the first place: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawing_Hands

Comment: The problem is that there are tests based on drawing, but they are to assess other things such as neglect syndrome. Check clock-drawing for neglect so you might be able to explain better what you mean by not able to the draw. Anyway, it might be useful to say that spatial IQ is the ability to perform mental representation and changes of spaces, so no mention of drawing.

Comment: "Therefore, people who can't draw obviously cannot." That's definitely not the case. A person might be able to visualize objects and even manipulate them in their mind (elongation, rotation, etc.) but not be able to reproduce this on paper. Doesn't imply that they have low IQ

Comment: @SerenaD when you are talking about neglect there, you need to be clear you are talking about **spacial** neglect (a behavioral syndrome occurring after brain injury). Saying just neglect can be interpreted as something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

Spatial IQ refers to the ability to perform navigation tasks, mental representation, and mental rotation of objects. Therefore, if you have a clear idea or 3D model in mind of what you want to draw but you are not able to reproduce it on paper, I would say does not mean you have a low spatial IQ.

Simple answer:

No. Bad drawing does not mean low spatial IQ

However, the inability of drawing can depend on other factors. Check Neglect syndrome and clock-drawing test.

Comment: Please can you cite some reputable sources of information to back your claims? Plus, when you are talking about neglect there, you need to be clear you are talking about spacial neglect (a behavioral syndrome occurring after brain injury). Saying just neglect can be interpreted as something completely different.